# How can I add option that user can't select earlier date from today?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar

How can I add option that user can't select earlier date from today?

My code :

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'
import { DateRangeInput } from '@datepicker-react/styled'

const initialState = {
  startDate: null,
  endDate: null,
  focusedInput: null,
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'focusChange':
      return { ...state, focusedInput: action.payload }
    case 'dateChange':
      return action.payload
    default:
      throw new Error()
  }
}

function CalendarData() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  return (
    <DateRangeInput
      onDatesChange={data => dispatch({ type: 'dateChange', payload: data })}
      onFocusChange={focusedInput => dispatch({ type: 'focusChange', payload: focusedInput })}
      startDate={state.startDate} // Date or null
      endDate={state.endDate} // Date or null
      focusedInput={state.focusedInput} // START_DATE, END_DATE or null
    />
  )
}


export default CalendarData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set start date as system default date, instead of null

```
const newDate = new Date();
const initialState = {
  startDate: newDate,
}
```